# how to Find MongoDB children documents whose all parents match a condition

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a Mongo Collection with data like this:

```
{
    "_id" : "PA69JtsyvDQg4vkhe",
    "createdby" : "pdLrKGkRMw9B97ghr",
    "parentid" : "meyk8FAFlfnasfkl",
    "displayname" : "1236206_10201717961929222_810113597_n.jpg",
    "uploadedAt" : ISODate("2015-11-03T08:05:30.702Z"),
    "shareids" : [ 
       "NTWvxkigfaLy4udQc", 
       "8Cds9BxaYxchvM7xK"
    ]
}
```

Each document has a parentid which is id of other document.

Now I want to find all the document whose all parents (parent, parent of parent,...) match a condition, for example, have createdby: myid.

Normally, I would write a query like this:

```
Collections.find({
   createdby:myid
})
```

to find all document created by myid. But in this case, I'm stuck.

I feel that there should be recursive queries to get this.

Please Help me to get the best solution for this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what expected output you want ?

Comment: @AlokDeshwal Will you please provide a detailed description of your problem with suitable collections consisting of relevant documents so that we can get idea regarding hierarchy

Comment: Sorry for not giving enough detail. I want a list of documents whose parent, grandparent (parent of parent),... match a condition.

Comment: @leizard-hcmus Yes, we got that. What Rubin was referring to is to get some ancestors of the example doc as well. But to cut a long story short: No recursions, no sub queries and no JOINS in MongoDB. The only thing we can do is to find an alternative solution for your problem. So please provide us with the problem, since the way you want to solve it, it simply isn't possible.